# Customizing Legend Shape in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

I am working on [Pie Chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart) in [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). I am trying to customize the default shape of legend. I could change the position of legend but Is it is possible to change the shape? Does it have any inbuilt property or we have to customize?

**HTML**

```
<div class="chart">
      <canvas baseChart
        [data]="pieChartData"
        [labels]="pieChartLabels"
        [chartType]="pieChartType"
        [options]="pieChartOptions"
        [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
        [colors]="pieChartColors"
        [legend]="pieChartLegend">
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
 public pieChartLabels: Label[] = [['Download', 'Sales'], ['In', 'Store', 'Sales'], 'Mail Sales'];
  public pieChartData: number[] = [300, 500, 100];
  public pieChartType: ChartType = 'pie';
      public pieChartOption: any = {
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
          labels: {
            fontSize: 10
          }
        }
      }
```

**What I want**
 [image: Expected o/p]

**What I am getting**

[image: o/p]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart) uses [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) and in chartjs there is **legend.labels.usePointStyle**, you have to make it true.

```
public pieChartLabels: Label[] = [['Download', 'Sales'], ['In', 'Store', 'Sales'], 
'Mail Sales'];
public pieChartData: number[] = [300, 500, 100];
public pieChartType: ChartType = 'pie';
  public pieChartOption: any = {
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
        fontSize: 10,
        usePointStyle: true
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome @ved. Worked for me. Can I move the legend to `right center` position. Is it is possible?

Comment: yes,  but available positions are 'top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right' .

Comment: you can follow this link https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3175 for making it in right center position